# Scale problem when using bevel along path

Tags: scale, bevel

In below image the orange vertices is/are the path and scale I would like the bevel (with an object) to follow but the gray shaded 3/4 ring is what I keep getting. I've applied  scale transform in object mode prior to making the 3/4 circle a path, but same results. tried 2D & 3D same result.
Other image is one side view of what I'm trying to create. Maybe there is a better approach?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe I solved the underlying problem (s). It wasn't a scaling issue but probably an origin issue of the path of the 3/4 arc- circle. Fixed by making sure my profile (bevel) path was at inside edge I wanted to be inside edge and then had the 3/4 circle path be at  3D curser (or center of circle) and reversed segment path.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved the underlying problem (s). It wasn't a scaling issue but probably an origin issue of the path of the 3/4 arc- circle. Fixed by making sure my profile (bevel) path was at inside edge I wanted to be inside edge and then had the 3/4 circle path be at 3D curser (or center of circle) and reversed segment path